# How to create new directory tenant via API/CLI without Azure stack?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am currently trying to work out how to automate the creation of new AAD tenants, however the only API I have found is one that uses Azure stack (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurestack/directorytenants/createorupdate).

Is there any way to create a new directory tenant via the API/CLI without azure stack?

I have checked the "az ad" docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/ad?view=azure-cli-latest) but they do not offer an option to create a new tenant, neither do the graph AAD APIs.

Thought there might be a way to create a new AAD instance using the generic resource creation CLI tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-create), but if there is I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a publicly available API for that

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for creating AAD tenants.